# Word meaning a certain phrase?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, expressions, synonyms, translation

In Estonian, there is a word that roughly translates to "I want to sleep more, but I can't, so I am laying in bed". Is there a similar word or shortened phrase that means the same thing in English?

Comment: Do you mean a single word or a phrase? NB It should  be _I am lying in bed_.

Comment: The title needs editing. I rejected an edit because I thought the only appropriate tag was  'single word request'. 'Word/short phrase describing when you lie awake in bed trying unsuccessfully to get to sleep'.

Comment: What is this word out of curiosity?

Answer (score 1):

A few thoughts: words like *sleepless* and  *wakefulness,* both describe an inability to sleep by one who desires sleep, though neither describes or requires being in bed at the time.

However, one who desires to sleep but is unable whilst laying in bed is often said to be, *tossing and turning*.

> toss and turn: *to move about and turn over in bed because one is unable to sleep* ([Websters](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/toss%20and%20turn))

Answer (score 0):

Well, "restless" can be used to describe someone who can't sleep so "I lay restless in bed but longing for sleep" could work or something similar to that such as "I lay in bed but the sleep I seek is out of reach". I hope this was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Insomnia describes the first part: "I want to sleep more, but I can't" but not the second: "so I'm laying in bed."  It can also name it as a geberal patrern, say over several weeks or as a medical condition.